# Water temperature control unit - what is the need for cold supply pressure?

Tags: water-pressure, temperature-control

[image]

*A typical industrial water temperature control unit. Image source: [Frigel](https://frigel.com).*

Our company uses water temperature control units (TCU) similar to the style shown above.
Ours have an electric immersion heater to bring the water up to temperature and an indirect cooling coil fed from the factory's central chilled water system to cool the water if the process is generating heat. To cool the system a solenoid valve on the inlet or outlet is energised.

One of the brands we use calls for a water pressure of several bar on the chilled water supply which means we have to raise the system pressure for the whole plant. The TCU monitors the pressure and won't run if it is not high enough.

I would have thought that it shouldn't care and that a small pressure difference between in and out would cause coolant to flow when the valve is open. Can anyone explain what problem the pressure requirement is addressing?

We'll be setting up a call with the vendor but I'm looking for ideas on what to discuss.

Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like it's just the system's way to monitor there is an effective cold water supply present.

Comment: high pressure may be necessary to get a desired flow rate through a filter.